# Get element at index from iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have a function like this:

```
void func(vector<LatLng>::iterator it_start,
           vector<LatLng>::iterator it_end)
{
    int middle_index = (it_end - it_start) / 2;
    // how can I now get the element at 'middle_index' ?
}
```

Can I now get the element at `middle_index` without passing the vector itself as a parameter ?

Comment: Note this is only safe if `it_start != it_end`.

Answer (score 4):

```
void func(vector<LatLng>::iterator it_start,
          vector<LatLng>::iterator it_end)
{
    int middle_index = (it_end - it_start) / 2;
    std::advance(it_start, middle_index);
    LatLng& mid = *it_start;
}
```

or simply

```
    LatLng& mid = *std::advance(it_start, (it_end - it_start) / 2);
```

or

```
    LatLng& mid = it_start[(it_end - it_start) / 2];
```

or using [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
    LatLng& mid = *std::next(it_start, middle_index);
```

Comment: I doubt he wants to advance `it_start`. And a mention of `std::next` would be good too.

Answer (score 1):

More reusable solution which works also for lists (if you make it template function or change parameter to `std::list<T>::iterator`) looks like:

```
void func(vector<LatLng>::iterator it_start,
          vector<LatLng>::iterator it_end)
{
    auto &mid = *std::next(it_start, std::distance(it_start, it_end)/2);
}
```